Different sets of hyperparameters for different types of penalties in logistic regression using Vertex AI Hyperparameter Tuning?
I want to train a logistic regressor (scikit-learn) using Vertex AI's Hyperparameter Tuning. I know I can use CategoricalParameterSpec on the different solvers. However, different solvers use different hyperparameters (e.g., lbfgs can only use l2 penalty whereas liblinear can use l1 and l2).
Is it possible to specify this in one tuning job, or do I have to create different tuning jobs for different solvers?

Yes it is possible to specify different solvers in one tuning  . Check this doc Vertex AI creates trials of your training job with different sets of hyperparameters . Let me know if you are looking for this

I am aware of this. What I'm trying to find is if it's possible, for example: I'm training a Logistic Regression model. I have a trial with 'saga' as the solver. I want the values it will use for penalty as any of ['elasticnet', 'l1', 'l2', None]. However, if the solver is 'lbfgs', I want the penalty to only be restricted to ['l2', None]. I'm just afraid that if I still use the entire list of penalties for solvers that don't use some of them, I will be wasting the trial.
